# package com.google.gson does not exist. build failure error in spring GSON

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring, gson

I am trying to pass a list of objects to `ajax` from my spring MVC controller. I'm using `GSON` to convert the list and parse it after it's been received in the ajax call.
It works fine. But when I try build my project I get the following error.

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project SkillSet: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
>   [ERROR] /C:/Users/muralil/SkillSet2/SkillSet - Copy/src/main/java/com/skillset/controller/EmployeeController.java:[25,23] package com.google.gson does not exist
>   [ERROR] /C:/Users/muralil/SkillSet2/SkillSet - Copy/src/main/java/com/skillset/controller/EmployeeController.java:[154,17] cannot find symbol
>   [ERROR] symbol:   class Gson
>   [ERROR] location: class com.skillset.controller.EmployeeController
>   [ERROR] /C:/Users/muralil/SkillSet2/SkillSet - Copy/src/main/java/com/skillset/controller/EmployeeController.java:[154,31] cannot find symbol
>   [ERROR] symbol:   class Gson
>   [ERROR] location: class com.skillset.controller.EmployeeController

I have included the gson jar file in the project's build path and also the lib folder inside webapps. I have no clue why there is a build failure. Also when I go ahead and start the server the code works perfectly fine!

I tried adding the following dependency to my `pom.xml` with no luck

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I got the following error

> Could not resolve dependencies for project SkillSet:SkillSet:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4: Could not transfer artifact com.google.code.gson:gson:pom:2.2.4 from/to central (repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Not authorized by proxy , ReasonPhrase:Proxy Authentication Required. -> [Help 1] [ERROR] –

I fixed it by going to the settings.xml file in your maven folder and setting proxy settings :) Now my build is successfully completed

Comment: You are mixing maven with your IDE way to configure dependencies. In order to build your maven project, you need to specify your dependencies in your pom.xml. Also, all decent IDEs have maven integration, so all you need is to define the proper dependencies in pom.xml. You won't need to handle the lib folder manually

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. i tried adding the dependencies and i get the following error. Could not resolve dependencies for project SkillSet:SkillSet:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4: Could not transfer artifact com.google.code.gson:gson:pom:2.2.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Not authorized by proxy , ReasonPhrase:Proxy Authentication Required. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

Comment: Are you in a restricted network? can you access http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.4/gson-2.2.4.pom in your browser? Do you have a proxy configured in your settings.xml? If so, verify if your proxy settings are correct. http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Comment: Yes i had to modify my proxy settings and it worked. thanks :)